# Use the value of a function that is inside an each. function for the .each function (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following part of my function should show the distance between lots of lat/lng coordinates. It works perfect, till the "`console.log(dist)`" part below, but I cant get out this values from "dist" to each html "`i`".

```
$(".box").each(function() {
    var latlng = $(this).find('.area').data('latlng').split(',');
    var lat1 = latlng[0];
    var lon1 = latlng[1];
    var lat2 = location_lat.toFixed(8);
    var lon2 = location_lon.toFixed(8);
    
    distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, "K"); // <-- start calculate function
    
    function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
        if ((lat1 === lat2) && (lon1 === lon2)) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
            var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
            var theta = lon1-lon2;
            var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
            var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
            
            if (dist > 1) {
                dist = 1;
            }
            
            dist = Math.acos(dist);
            dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
            dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515; // M = statute miles (default)
            if (unit === "K") { dist = dist * 1.609344; } // K = kilometers
            if (unit === "N") { dist = dist * 0.8684; } // N = nautical miles

            console.log(dist); // <-- works perfect, I got all the different values
            
            var display = $(this).find('.area');
            $(display).find('i').html(dist.toFixed(0)).append(" <em>km</em>"); // <-- doesn´t work, just empty "i"
        }
    }
    
});
```

I also tried:

```
...
distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, "K"); // <-- start calculate function

var display = $(this).find('.area');
$(display).find('i').html(dist.toFixed(0)).append(" <em>km</em>"); // <-- doesn´t work, because "dist" is not defined
```

... but then "dist" will no longer work (error: disk is not defined). Whats wrong with my "`.each`" function? How can I get the values from the "distance function" back to the `.each` function part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `distance()` function outside of the loop and let it return the calculated value.

```
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
    if (lat1 === lat2 && lon1 === lon2) return 0;

    var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
    var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
    var theta = lon1-lon2;
    var radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
    var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
    
    if (dist > 1) dist = 1;
    
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515; // M = statute miles (default)
    if (unit === "K") { dist = dist * 1.609344; } // K = kilometers
    if (unit === "N") { dist = dist * 0.8684; } // N = nautical miles
    
    return dist;
}

$(".box").each(function() {
    var latlng = $(this).find('.area').data('latlng').split(',');
    var dist = distance(
        latlng[0],
        latlng[1],
        location_lat.toFixed(8),
        location_lon.toFixed(8),
        "K"
    );

    $(this).find('.area i').text(dist.toFixed(0)).append(" <em>km</em>");
});
```

Comment: Big thx for help! You are right, works perfect! There are just two little errors in your code, if I am right. "return 0;" must be "{return 0;}" and "dist = 1;" must be "{dist = 1;}"

Comment: @Pepe No, not necessarily. `if (something) return;` is completely valid Javascript, the curly braces are unnecessary for one-liners like this. If you want to write them, you can, but it's not required.